# Make IE trust the website launched from Mac

Tags: internet-explorer, localhost, ssl-certificate

I'm debugging a website on my machine. I use a Mac and Parallels Desktop where Windows is installed as virtual machine.

I can launch the website under Mac. `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` works well under Mac; `10.211.55.2` in IE under Windows points well to the website too. But I got an `This site is not secure` error. If I click on `Go on the webpage (not recommended)`, we could still see contents for most of the pages. But it seems that [cross-storage](https://github.com/zendesk/cross-storage) does not work because of this certificate problem.

[image]

After clicking on `Go on to the webpage (not recommended)`, we could see the details of the certificate. But I don't find the place to install it.

Does anyone know how to make IE trust this website launched from Mac, so that cross-storage is not blocked?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a certificate mismatch issue.

In snapshot, it shows that the certificate is ok but still you are receiving the error.

I suggest you try to clear all data for the site and again try to access the site to see whether it resolve the issue.

If the issue persists and if you think that site is safe for access then you can try to disable **Warn about certificate address mismatch** option.

To disable this option, you can refer to the steps below.

(1) Go to Tools (ALT + X).

(2) Click on Internet options.

(3) Go to the Advanced tab.

(4) Scroll to the bottom in Settings options.

(5) Find and uncheck the **Warn about certificate address mismatch** option.

[image]

(6) Click on OK to close the dialog.

(7) Close the IE browser and restart the machine.

**Note:** It is not recommended to disable **Warn about certificate address mismatch** option.

Comment: Thank you... I tried to uncheck the `Warn about certificate address mismatch` and reboot several times. It did not have any impact on "certificate error" or "This site is not secure"...

Comment: There are some other certificate-related options in the advanced tab. try to uncheck them and see the results. For testing purposes, try to lower down the security settings and check to see whether it fixes the issue or not. It can help to narrow down the issue.